# Any consideration for oracle installation which need to be done in OS installation?

Tags: linux, centos, system-installation

Please forgive me if I post the question in the inappropriate place. Because I am not sure if it belongs to the [DBA SO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Thanks.

I am trying to install CentOS 64bit in the VMware for Oracle 11g 64bit. But didn't know what things should be done or something should be emphasized during the installation of CentOS for the Oracle 11g.
Currently, I didn't found any document mentioned that.

So I list the things I can down here:

1. What does the Partitions layout look like? Has anyone a good example?
2. Should I create TMP partition for the installation of Oracle 11g? How much should it be?
3. Is it better assign a specified partition for the Oracle DataBase? Should any things be thought about ?
4. How much size of SWAP partition?

Thanks.

Comment: Oracle has documentation on which directories it uses for various purposes. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/appendix_ofa.htm#LADBI1377  You can mount any of these base directories on their own disk volumes if you think they will grow a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for testing/developments puposes or a production system?
How many HD do you have?
Are they the same?

1. If it is for non production, than you can give Oracle one partition from each HD.
2. If you can spare some disks you can create a few Gigabytes of TMP partition on another HD. If not, then it's OK as well.
3. No real need to assign a specific partition to Oracle. When you install Oracle you will be asked were to place the default data and afterwards you can add new disk space (Tablespace)

Thanks
Alon Peled

Comment: currently, I just building my development/testing environment, But for the production. I have no idea what is the best pratice for the partitions schema for the oralce. Thanks.

Comment: If you have several HD, it can be evenly divide the data among them or use them as mirror.